# how to desactivate lazy loading for entity framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

```
public class Country : Item
{
    public string           Code
    {get; set;}

    public string CodePhone
    { get; set; }
    public string           Name
    {get; set;}
    public string Flag
    { get; set; }
    public decimal?         Latitude
    {get; set;}
    public decimal?         Longitude
    {get; set;}

    public int              RegionsCount
    {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("DefaultCurrency")]
    public int? DefaultCurrencyID
    {get; set;}
    public virtual Currency DefaultCurrency
    { get; set; }

    public ContinentType ContinentType
    { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Property> 
                            Properties 
    {get; set;}

    public ICollection<CountryLocale>
                            CountryLocales
    { get; set; }
}

public class CountryLocale : ItemLocale
{
    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public int                  CountryID
    {get; set;}

    public Country
                            Country
    {get; set;}

    public string                   FullName
    {get;set;}
}

 public TEntity Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where, params string[] includes)
    {
        var model = this.DbSet;

        foreach (var property in includes)
        {
            model.AsExpandable().Include(property);
        }

        return model.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
    }

this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Country country = this._CountryRepository.Get(p=>p.ID ==  this.CountryID, new string[] { "CountryLocales" });
```

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
line : CountryLocale countrylo = country.CountryLocales.First();

i got this error when trying to desactivate lazyloading for performance reasons. how can i resolve the problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you disabled `LazyLoading` you need to manually load the child properties of your main object with `Include`

```
var country = db.Country.Include("CountryLocales");
```

The other way around would be:

- Dont disable lazy load and use `include` in your queries.
- Try including your child objects one by one until you feel the
  performance is better.
- Usually if you know you will iterate over a
  child object you should use include in your query for that child
  object.
- remeber to include second level child if you need to access a property of that level... `Include("Parent.Child")`